# Kong 1.0.3 host required field missing

Tags: kong

I'm new to Kong and facing a problem when I tried to **POST** a **service** using **Kong 1.0.3**

Here is the POST URL sent using Postman

```
http://localhost:8001/services?name=GOT&protocol=https&host=anapioficeandfire.com&path=/api
```

[Screenshot with the Postman UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIZU3.png)

And the error 400 Bad Request I'm getting, while host is clearly specified

```
{
    "message": "schema violation (host: required field missing)",
    "name": "schema violation",
    "fields": {
        "host": "required field missing"
    },
    "code": 2
}
```

However, when I follow the Kong get started to create a service I'm not facing any issue. This command works fine :

```
curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://localhost:8001/services/ \
  --data 'name=example-service' \
  --data 'url=http://mockbin.org'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, curl with "--data" to send POST request, so put all params in your request (after "?") into BODY in postman, click send and you will get success!

[image: this is my postman request's image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem with the `url` parameter

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "protocol": "https",
    "port": 8061,
    "path": "/api/v1/testapi",
    "retries": 5,
    "connect_timeout": 60000,
    "write_timeout": 60000,
    "read_timeout": 60000,
    "tags": [
        "testing"
    ],
    "url": "/a/vpi1/testapi", --remove this to resolve this error
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.MQ.Lu-KcR4aCeuT9hi1K474zV3s4VaopLDCcf4nZvH6DQo",
    "host": "localhost"
}
```

from this json request remove
`"url": "/api/v1/testapi"`
this

this will work

updated Request

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "protocol": "https",
    "port": 8061,
    "path": "/api/v1/testapi",
    "retries": 5,
    "connect_timeout": 60000,
    "write_timeout": 60000,
    "read_timeout": 60000,
    "tags": [
        "testing"
    ],
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.MQ.Lu-KcR4aCeuT9hi1K474zV3s4VaopLDCcf4nZvH6DQo",
    "host": "localhost"
}
```

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yJyC.png)

hope this will work

Comment: Please highlight and explain what you have changed.